# After reinstalling ATI graphics drivers, my keyboard and mouse aren't working anymore

Tags: 11.04, fglrx

On Ubuntu 11.04 I tried to install the open source drivers for my laptops ATI Mobility Radeon 5470M but I messed that up a bit and lost xserver. Now I've managed to solve that problem with [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a__Need_to_fully_remove_-fglrx_and_reinstall_-ati_from_scratch) and by downloading the ATI proprietary drivers and install those manually.

Now, when Ubuntu loads up I get to the login screen but I can't use my mouse or my keyboard (usb keyboard and mouse doesn't work either). If I use the recovery console, then login with that and then run 'startx'. I can login fine (though Unity doesn't show, the graphics seem to be working because it shows the fading animation of libnotify), but I can't type or move my mouse.

Comment: Are you still looking for help or did you solve this problem? If you did find an answer please consider adding it below, thanks :)

Comment: I didn't, I did a fresh install :(